# How to get UISelectMany custom component value in a managed bean

Tags: jsf, components

I have a project which consist in a treeview of a folder.

I decided to create a custom component.

The XHTML looks great, I can get the request param of the selected files on the decode method.

The problem is: I can't obtain the value on a managedBean attribute (see submit method)...

here is my code, I don't understand what is wrong or I miss...

**Custom Component**

```
@FacesComponent(createTag = true, tagName = "indexComponent", namespace = "http://index.com/tags")
public class IndexComponent extends UISelectMany{

    private String pathString = "/home/test/";

    private List<Path> filesNames = new ArrayList<>();

    private static String NAME_CHKBOX = "checkbox";

    IndexComponent instance = this;

    public IndexComponent getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setInstance(IndexComponent instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }


    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return "treeview";
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException{

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("ul", this);
        writer.writeAttribute("data-role", "treeview", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", this.getClientId(context), null);

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(pathString), new HashSet<>(),2, new FileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                filesNames.add(dir);
                writer.startElement("li", instance);    
                writer.writeAttribute("data-caption", dir.getFileName() , null);
                writer.writeAttribute("class", "" , null);
                writer.startElement("ul", instance);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                filesNames.add(file);
                writer.startElement("li", instance);
                writer.startElement("input", instance);                 
                writer.writeAttribute("type", "checkbox" , null);
                writer.writeAttribute("name", getHtmlNameCheckBox(context)  , null);
                writer.writeAttribute("value", file.getFileName() , null);
                writer.writeAttribute("data-role", "checkbox" , null);
                writer.writeAttribute("data-caption", file.getFileName() , null);
                writer.writeAttribute("title", "" , null);
                writer.endElement("input");
                writer.endElement("li");

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                writer.endElement("li");
                writer.endElement("ul");

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                writer.startElement("li", instance);
                writer.writeAttribute("data-caption", file.getFileName() , null);
                writer.endElement("li");

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

        });

        writer.endElement("ul");

        instance.encodeEnd(context);
    }

    public List<Path> getFilesNames() {
        return filesNames;
    }


    public void setFilesNames(List<Path> filesNames) {
        this.filesNames = filesNames;
    }


    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context) {

        String[] result = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterValuesMap().get( getHtmlNameCheckBox(context) );

        if(result != null && result.length > 0) {
            List<String> liste = Arrays.asList( result );
            this.setSubmittedValue(liste);
        }
    }

    private String getHtmlNameCheckBox(FacesContext context){
        return String.format("%s:%s", this.getClientId(context), NAME_CHKBOX);
    }

}
```

**ManadgeBean**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private List<String> filesNames;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        filesNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void submit() {
        LogUtils.info("submit !!!");

        for (String s : filesNames) {
            LogUtils.info(s);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getFilesNames() {
        return filesNames;
    }

    public void setFilesNames(List<String> filesNames) {
        this.filesNames = filesNames;
    }

}
```

**XHTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:t="http://index.com/tags"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="metro-all.css" library="css" />
        <h:outputScript name="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" library="js" />
        <h:outputScript name="metro.js" library="js" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>                
            <t:indexComponent value="#{indexBean.filesNames}" />    
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{indexBean.submit()}" type="submit" styleClass="button primary" value="Submit" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</h:html>
```

Note : I don't want to use Primefaces or other framework.